# What is the naming convention for side effectful functions in Java?

Tags: java, function, lambda

Pretty much title. I need to differentiate between something scary and something safe without having to look inside the function body. What is the standard in Java? I can't put "!" in function names.

Example:

```
// convenient when you don't want to update the reference in the objects that were using 
// param 
BiFunction<T,U,T> mutableTransformation = (param,operand) -> {
    //... do operations that alter param using operand    
    return param;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that there's a universally-accepted convention for that.

Comment: could you give an example of two such functions? As EJoshuaS noted, I can't think of a universal convention for that.

Comment: @EJoshuaS but the need to differentiate is there, right? Or am I doing something wrong? maybe a convention should be set...

Comment: I think that heavily depends on the specific content of the method. A method name should reflect method content - so how should we be able to recommend you names for methods with unknown content?

Comment: Also, I think as long as the name reflects the purpose of the function, it should be easy to infer whether or not the function carries out side effects or is pure. I wouldn't expect an `add` function to carry out side effects, but would expect a `print` function to. As long as your names are descriptive, I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: If one function has side-effects and another doesn't, then they're most likely sufficiently different that they should have entirely different names. See e.g. [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) methods.

Comment: Method names should reflect their purpose, not their implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, any method starting with `set` has a side effect. As a recent convention (since Java 8), methods with `of` or `with` in their names are side effect-free. Examples are the new date/time classes in the `java.time` package.

Comment: With the exception of `BigDecimal` and similar classes that are immutable.

Comment: Indeed. If `BigDecimal` had been created in Java 8, its `setScale` method probably would have been called `withScale`.

Comment: That isn't a convention for being free of side effects but for what the methods do. Making, for example, a `Duration` out **of** milliseconds is called `ofMillis`. Adding a `Duration` to another is called `plus`. Yes, these are side-effect free, but that's not the point of the names.